# If condition naming convention

Tags: java, boolean, coding-style, naming-conventions

I have a boolean function that checks if scandata keys are valid. I named it as :

```
areScandataKeysValid()
```

For naming conventions, should it be named as isScandataDataKeysValid() or like how I did above?. In Clean Code book, I only saw examples with **is** version. So, I'm confused which one makes sense? Grammatically, "**are**" thats for sure.

Comment: Doesn't that naming convention usually only applies to getters ? e.g. getProperty becomes isProperty if the property is boolean, but you wouldn't expect any method returning a boolean to begin with is

Comment: What's the name of the class in question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `isName()` convention is part of the JavaBeans standard, and applies to boolean-valued properties.

- If your API does not need to be JavaBeans compatible, you can ignore the convention.
- If your method for checking the scan keys is not intended as a getter for a  "property", the `isName()` convention does not apply.

I share your preference for `areScandataKeysValid` over `isScandataKeysValid`, because of the grammatical dissonance.  There are other alternatives to consider; e.g.

- `hasValidScandataKeys` for a predicate, or
- `validateScandataKeys` or `checkScandataKeys` for a method that (typically) throws an exception to indicate invalidity.

I am not aware of any documented conventions (i.e. style guides) that favor any one of the above.  (Nothing says that "good grammar" is essential.)

Bottom line: your choice.

Answer (score 0):

I think "is" or "are" is superfluous. The most important thing is that a predicate function has an adjective as the last word. Therefor I would name the method *scanDataKeysValid*, or if it's clear from the context of the class, simply *keysValid*.